# How does the spread operator help in fetching data in my case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how to write the title of this question. But...

I have a `Details.jsx` component which invokes `getProduct function` that is inside `ProductsContext.jsx`. This function returns information about a single product from a list of products. At first I had trouble because the function kept returning nothing I guess. I tried loading the title of a single product but it kept showing `can't read property of undefined`. I guess it was because `ProductsContext` hasn't fetched the data yet, so the function kept returning nothing.

```
//ProductsContext.jsx
function getProduct(id) {
 const product = products.find(item => item.id == id)
 return product
}


//Details.jsx
const {id} = getParams() //react-router-dom
const {getProduct} = useContext(ProductsContext)
const product = getProduct(id) //throws undefined when rendering

return(
  <img src={product.image} /> {/* error: can't read property image of undefined */}
)
```

what returned was `undefined`

But when I did this it worked

```
//ProductsContext.jsx
function getProduct(id) {
 const product = products.find(item => item.id == id)
 return {...product}
}
```

Why did using the `spread operator` work?

Comment: products.find(item => item.id == id)
will return undefined if the condition in callback does not match for  the products array and your function(getProduct) will return undefined. 
But, When you used {...}. The function will return {} in case of "undefined"

Comment: what @rashijain mentioned is correct. By adding spread operator it return object whether with or without product. If you try to get something from object and if its not available. It will return undefined. In this case  when return via spread, src set to `undefined` if value is not available. So basically it suppressing your error

Comment: @ShubhamVerma so basically whats happening is while the data is being fetched, the "getProduct()" returns an empty object and after the data is fetched it returns the product object? But is this a right way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure how you have write code. But you can say  that if product comes asynchronously. Generally in those type of case where data is async ideally put loader so that by the time data isn't available component shouldn't render where that data is required